# Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 The object 'SO_Not_Null' is dependent on column 'SO'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone tell me how to remove the dependency.

```
Alter Table NYM_Player_Stats
    Alter Column SO char(38)
```

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The object 'SO_Not_Null' is dependent on column 'SO'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 4
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SO failed because one or more objects access this column.

Table structure:

```
Team (PK, nchar(10), not null)
Year (nchar (10), not null)
SO (numeric (18,0)
AB (char (38), not null)
Runs (char (38) not null)
Hits (char(38) not null)
```

Comment: Is this a foreign key `SO_Not_Null` ?

Comment: No, there are no foreign keys.

Comment: What is `SO_Not_Null` ?

Comment: It is a column in the table.

Comment: How is `SO` and `SO_Not_Null` related ?

Comment: Year (Nchar)                                                                                                   Player (Char)                                                                                                                   Games (char)                                                                                                           AB (char)

Comment: SO (Numeric (18,0), Not Null)

Comment: Could you run the query `select TYPE from sys.objects where NAME='so_not_null'` and post the result?

Comment: Ran `select TYPE from sys.objects where NAME='so_not_null'` and the results are: `Type: 1 C`

Answer (score 1):

> Ran select TYPE from sys.objects where NAME='so_not_null' and the results are Type 1 C

A type of `C` [indicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx) that SO_NOT_NULL is a [check constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187550.aspx).  To alter the column definition, you will need to first remove the constraint.  The constraint can be recreated after the column is altered.

To do so, complete the following steps:

1. Execute `SELECT DEFINITION FROM SYS.CHECK_CONSTRAINTS WHERE NAME='so_not_null'` to get the constraint definition.  Save the output.
2. To remove the constraint, execute the statement `ALTER TABLE NYM_PLAYER_STATS DROP CONSTRAINT SO_NOT_NULL`.
3. Run the `ALTER TABLE` statement in your original question to update the column definition.
4. If desired, recreate the original constraint by executing `ALTER TABLE NYM_PLAYER_STATS ADD CONSTRAINT SO_NOT_NULL CHECK (<STATEMENT>)`, replacing `<STATEMENT>` with the definition from step 1.